# Error : Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String

Tags: file, codeigniter, extjs, upload, compiler-errors

I have a problem with my code.
I'm trying to make upload file form using ExtJS and Codeigniter.

Here is my code below,

```
 Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.field.File',
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.window.MessageBox'
]);

Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Upload a Photo',
        width: 400,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        frame: true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'filefield',
            name: 'photo',
            fieldLabel: 'Photo',
            labelWidth: 50,
            msgTarget: 'side',
            allowBlank: false,
            anchor: '100%',
            buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Upload',
            handler: function() {
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                if(form.isValid()){
                    form.submit({
                        url: '../upload',
                        waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                        success: function(fp, o) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: o.data.url,
                                method: "GET",
                                success: function(response, request) {
                                    // do whatever you need to with the generated HTML
                                    alert(response.responseText);
                                },
                                failure: function(response, request) {
                                    alert('failed');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }]
    });

});
```

But my console output showing error like "Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String".
So, if anyone have a same problem or was solving this issue, tell me please..

THANKS!!!

**CONCLUSION :**
oh I see..
Actually I'm use Codeigniter as my framework.
this problem will be solved if I return json to this url..

```
url: '../upload',
waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
success: function(fp, o) {
Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: o.data.url,
   method: "GET",
   success: function(response, request) {
      // do whatever you need to with the generated HTML
      alert(response.responseText);
   },
   failure: function(response, request) {
      alert('failed');
   }
   });
```

So, I create my controller like this (as sample)..

```
public function upload(){
        echo json_encode(1);
    }
```

and no more error result for my code..
THANKS Broncha!!

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX response is not a pure JSON. Try to output the `response` in console

```
success: function(response, request) {
  // do whatever you need to with the generated HTML
  console.log(response);
},
```

and check if the response is pure JSON

Answer (score 0):

My problem is same and I search on Google just know a solution for this problem
[URL Solution here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?248357-Uncaught-Ext.JSON.decode%28%29-You-re-trying-to-decode-an-invalid-JSON-String)

I think this is a difference using Sencha Free and Purchase. 
When using `Form.load(...)` to get JSON object mapping to all textfield of form, you not only wrote json string truthly but also keep like this format :

```
{success:true,data:{... json string object ...}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem similar to this but I actually had access to the server code to make changes.

ExtJS4

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Thing', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
model : 'MyApp.model.Thing',
autoLoad : true,

proxy : {
    type : 'jsonp', // Needs to be used because we are going cross domain
    url : 'http://remotehost:8081/Servlet',
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        totalProperty : 'totalCount',
        root : items,
        successProperty : 'success',
    },
} });
```

Java Servlet

```
...
String cb = request.getParameter("callback");
response.setContentType("application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8");
usersObject.put("totalCount", usersCount);
usersObject.put("success", true);
usersObject.put("items", itemsArray);
response.getWriter().write(cb + '(' + itemsObject.toString() + ')');
...
```

This is key:

response.getWriter().write(**cb + '(' + itemsObject.toString() + ')'**);

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error under Struts 2.

All I had to do was to use the following in struts.xml:

```
<result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
    <param name="inputName">someBeanAttribute</param>
</result>
```

So, basically you need to specify `application/json` somewhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UploadHelper {
    /**
     * @param responseContext
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void writeHtmlResponse(String responseContext) throws IOException {
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        Writer writer = ServletActionContext.getResponse().getWriter();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("<html>\n");
        sb.append("\n<pre>");
        sb.append(responseContext);
        sb.append("</pre>\n");
        sb.append("<script type='text/javascript'> \n window.name='").append(responseContext).append("';").append("</script>");
        sb.append("\n</html>");
        writer.write(sb.toString());
        writer.close();
    }
}
```